# rails devise hook into on_login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm looking to hook into devise after login / after session create. How would I go about doing this?

Basically I want to set a users location every time they login, and to do that I need an after login hook of sorts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devise updates the value of the `user.current_sign_in_at` timestamp on successful login.  So, you could simply add a `before_save` filter to your User model.  In that filter, check to see if the value of this field has changed, and if it has, set the users location.

BTW - I'm not sure what you mean by "location" - if you mean IP address, Devise already stores that for you.

Comment: Not to be critical, but I'd be concerned about mixing 'controller'-type logic (which page to direct someone to) in the model class. This seems to muddy the clean separation of Model-View-Controller.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of this! I'm using their IP to get their aprox location with Geocoder and then finding the nearest city in a database of cities we maintain. This should work perfectly, thanks very much.

Comment: Kevin - by "location" he didn't mean URL (which wasn't clear initially).

Comment: Ah yes sorry about that, geographic location not browser location.

Answer (score 10):

Devise is built on Warden, so you can use Warden's after_authentication hook.

Put this in an initializer:

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user,auth,opts|
  # do something with user
end
```

The remote IP address and other request info is stored in auth.request (i.e. auth.request.remote_ip).

See https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/callbacks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a page from the devise wiki: [How To: Redirect to a specific page on successful sign in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in).

In summary, the recommendation is to add the following method to the application controller:

> app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    custom_location_for(resource) || welcome_path
end
```

In the above code, `resource` means the object (user, account, etc) that you've implemented devise authentication for. (The object that has the `devise_for` in your routes.)

Comment: On my end this is actually causing an issue with registrations process. In my case, registration controller -> confirmation email -> confirmation controller and then directly to sign_in_and_redirect, which seems to skip the after_sign_in_path_for ... Might be a localized issue, but worth testing in every case ;)